# How to use middleware for multiple type of admins in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am using middleware in laravel. I have two middleware one is admin and second one is commissioner

Now in both middlewares some routes access to both middleware and some are not. Now what happen is i want personal routes of admin middleware not be accessed in commissioner middleware.
Here i have tried:-

```
//Admin Middleware Route
Route::group(["middleware" => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/users', 'AdminController@users');
});
//Commissioner Middleware Route
Route::group(["middleware" => ['commissioner']], function () {
 //we can put later on these routes
});

// common middleware routes between commissioner and admin
Route::group(["middleware" => ['admin','commissioner']], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/profile', 'AdminController@profile');
});
```

Now when i access the **AdminController@users** route when i login through commissioner it is accessible but i want that route not be accessed in when commissioner login. but **AdminController@dashboard** and **AdminController@profile**  should be accessible in both middleware

```
When admin login then  type is : master
when commsioner login then type  is : commissioner

// Commissioner Middleware
class Commissioner
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(empty(Session::has('adminSession'))){
        return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('flash_message_error', 'Please Login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}

// admin Middleware
class Admin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(empty(Session::has('adminSession'))){
        return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('flash_message_error', 'Please Login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Please help me i am using laravel 5.2. Thanks in advnace :)

Comment: Why your Commissioner middleware checks "Session::has('adminSession')", is it a typo? Should it be "Session::has('commissionerSession')"?

Comment: No it is adminsession beacuse the commsioner is also saved in admin table and having different type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have one admin table which contains tow different types of admins: master and commissioner.
These two types of admins are both logined in by invoke AdminController@login method. You want to use middleware to check the types of the admin to protect your routes.

Below is my suggestions:

1. Create three different middlewares:

   - AdminAuth middleware (give it a name in Http/Kernel.php as "admin") for authentication checking for both master and commissioner.
   - Master middleware (give it a name in Http/Kernel.php as "master") check master type admin.
   - Commissioner middleware (give it a name in Http/Kernel.php as "commissioner") check commissioner type admin.

Middlewares:

```
class AdminAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Session::has('adminSession')){
            return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('flash_message_error', 'Please Login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

class Master
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $admin = ... // Your code to retrived authenticated admin instance.
        if($admin->type !== 'master') { // I assume you have a type field.
            // return error here to indicate user is not a master
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

class Commissioner
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $admin = ... // Your code to retrived authenticated admin instance.
        if($admin->type !== 'commissioner') { // I assume you have a type field.
            // return error here to indicate user is not a commissioner
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. Update your route like below:

Routes:

```
//Admin Middleware Route can only be accessed by master admin
Route::group(["middleware" => ['admin', 'master']], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/users', 'AdminController@users');
});

//Commissioner Middleware Route
Route::group(["middleware" => ['admin', 'commissioner']], function () {
    //we can put later on these routes
});

// common middleware routes between commissioner and admin
Route::group(["middleware" => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/profile', 'AdminController@profile');
});
```

BTW, the middlewares are "AND" relationship. Say you have below declaration in your routes:

`"middleware" => ['admin', 'commissioner']`

This means the route can be accessed only when you passed both 'admin' and 'commissioner' checking.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It helps me